# How to store table table in array format in single row in database table using laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

In the below table I have been using data to store in a array format
which should be stored in a single row in database table.

```
 <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>transaction_number</th>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>item_number</th>
            <th>desc</th>
            <th>variant_code</th>
            <th>quantity</th>
            <th>cost</th>
        </tr>
        @php ($current_transaction_number = null)

        @foreach ($items as $item)
            @if ($loop->index > 0 && $current_transaction_number != $item->transaction_number)
               @include ('subtotal', compact('items', 'current_transaction_number'))
            @endif
            <tr>
                @if ($current_transaction_number == $item->transaction_number)
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                @else
                    @php ($current_transaction_number = $item->transaction_number)
                    <td>{{ $item->transaction_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->date }}</td>
                @endif
                <td>{{ $item->item_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->desc }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->variant_code }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->cost }}</td>
            </tr>


@if ($loop->last)
               @include ('subtotal', compact('items', 'current_transaction_number'))
               @include ('total', compact('items'))
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the question fully, and I don't see the reason for storing all of that data in one column, but you can definitely do that using `MySQL JSON field`.

In your migration use `$table->json('name_of_the_column')->nullable();` to create this column.

In your model add:

```
protected $casts = [
     'name_of_the_column' => 'array'
];
```

Then you will be able to retrieve stuff like `Model::where('name_of_the_column->name_of_the_property', 'Key')->get();`

For more details, you can see this link: https://www.qcode.in/use-mysql-json-field-in-laravel/

I hope this helps.

Comment: how to fetch the table data in controller

Comment: actually i was using multiple foreach and multiple tables inside a single form.i was storing data in a single coulmn in an because i have large amount of data from clients so when i use multiple columns and row my project database will take more space

Comment: You will fetch the data in controller like this:

`Model::where('name_of_the_column->name_of_the_property', 'Key')->get();`

See the link that I posted above.